# Bash loop over a list of elements

Tags: bash, list, loops

I've got a script I use that looks like this

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/supertab
git pull
cd ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic
git pull
cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-alternate
git pull
cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-easymotion
git pull
cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-matchit
git pull
cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-togglemouse
git pull
```

I'd like to update it so it loops through a list so I could have some improved output without having repeated explicit code. I'm very bad at shell scripting and wondering if it's possible to have a bash script that would run something like this if it was done in C

```
vector<string> v{"supertab" , "syntastic", "vim-alternate", 
                 "vim-easymotion", "vim-matchit", "vim-togglemouse"};
for (string it : v) {
    system("cd ~/.vim/bundle/" + it);
    cout << it << ": ";
    system("git pull");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an array in Bash, like this :

```
rootDir="~/.vim/bundle/"
runDir=$(pwd)
declare -a lstDir
lstDir=("supertab" "syntastic" "vim-alternate" "vim-easymotion" "vim-matchit" "vim-togglemouse")

for file in "${lstDir[@]}"; do
    cd "$rootDir/$file" && git pull
done

cd "$runDir"
```

Comment: +1 for the more robust `cd` approach and conscientious double-quoting.

Answer (score 4):

Where you are:

```
 cd ~/.vim/bundle
 for f in supertab syntastic vim-alternate vim-easymotion vim-matchit vim-togglemouse
 do
    cd $f
    git pull
    cd ..
 done
```

Comment: It is often more robust to not `cd ..` inside a script/loop. If something goes wrong, like one of the directories doesn't exist, your script will keep `cd ..` to the wrong place and potentially do damage or mess things up in the filesystem. Better assign `base=~/.vim/bundle` and then `cd $base/$f` in the loop.

Comment: `( cd "$f" && git pull )` is even better than that